# Android soft keyboard reverts to default keyboard on orientation change

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I'm building an android soft keyboard and I can't seem to fix this bug - I have an Arabic and QWERTY keyboard and when I rotate my device on the QWERTY keyboard (or even Arabic shift), it's as if my program has "restarted" and it becomes the Arabic Keyboard without shift.

The `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` does not work because my application does not extend `Activity` but `InputMethodService`.

I put the following in my android manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize">
```

I tried using

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.i(MYDEBUG, "Config Changed " + currentKeyboard.equals(qwerty));

    }
```

However, `currentKeyboard.equals(qwerty))` always results to false and I made sure it was true just before the orientation change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, after mind boggling thinking I realized the issue was with the line of code `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);`

When removed, my code would change orientation but my keyboard would not be resized. Since I love the re-sizing feature of the parent, I made an array that contains all the keyboards and after changing orientation, I would update the array so that the keyboard array would have the right sizes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    int currentKeyboard = 0;
    boolean isShifted = kv.isShifted();
    for (int i = 0; i < keyboard.length; i++) {
        if(kv.getKeyboard().equals(keyboard[i])){
            currentKeyboard = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    initializeKeyboardArray();
    setKeyboard(keyboard[currentKeyboard]);
    kv.setShifted(isShifted);

}

private void initializeKeyboardArray(){
    keyboard = new Keyboard[7];
    keyboard[ARABIC] = arabic;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SHIFT] = arabicShift;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS] = arabicSymbols;
    keyboard[ARABIC_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = arabicSymbolsShift;
    keyboard[QWERTY] = qwerty;
    keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS] = qwertySymbols;
    keyboard[QWERTY_SYMBOLS_SHIFT] = qwertySymbolsShift;
}
```

Not sure if this is a roundabout way of solving the problem or if this is the right way so if anyone knows a better way - please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the applications fault.  If the application is restarting on orientation changes, then your input connection is being torn down and rebuilt to a new edit text.  This means the keyboard would see it as a new connection and will start in the default state.  To test this, write a test app that turns off restarts on configuration change and see if it still happens to keyboards in that app.

Comment: Sorry how do I stop the application from restarting? I thought adding the line of code in the manifest stops it from doing that.

Comment: Adding it to the application's manifest does that.  Adding it to the keyboard's doesn't.  It would just stop the keyboard service from being restarted.

Comment: Sorry you sort of lost me.  I'm a little new in the field of android development. Do you think you can clarify what you said?  Thank you